# Javascript image noise detection

Tags: javascript, image-processing, noise, noise-reduction

I'm working on a project where I receive an array of images taken with cell phone cameras, which vary wildly in quality. I want to exclude any images that have a high amount of image noise and then save/display the rest.

Every JS image processing library I've looked at so far mentions noise-reduction or the ability to add noise to a canvas image, neither of which fit my use case of simply needing to flag if an image is too noisy or not. Ideally, it would be something I could do in the browser with canvas, but I would also consider a server-side library where I could process the images there and send them back.

Is this at all possible? I do not have much knowledge when it comes to computer vision / image processing, and would appreciate any resources/libraries/approaches suggested.

Answer (score 2):

To detect noise you first need to know the properties of your useful data.

So if you have no prior knowledge of the input images then you Can not reliably detect noise.

There are many kind of noises. Usually noise is present in higher frequency ranges (dot artifact, grainy noise,...) But that is not always the case for example position distortion of image or lighting artifact are usually low frequency noise

Some approaches:

1. **The idea is knowing what the data should contain and filter out the rest**

   so detect if any frequency is present not consistent with your data via **FFT/DCT** and this should flag the noise out. The same goes for colors do a histogram and see if there are inconsistencies with expected histogram shape
2. **Know which kind of noise is present (by knowledge of how the data was obtained)**

   in this case you can specifically look for possible noise for example color analog **TV** signal was often noised with black or white dots especially during storms. So you could look for singular white and black dots almost evenly spaced along the whole image if found flag as noised ...

   As mentioned before there are a lot of kinds of noise caused by different things so if you know the **HW** config for data acquisition then you can estimate which noise could be present and specifically look for it.
3. **if you have no prior knowledge of the data or noise present**

   then you are out of luck because you can not reliably distinct noise from data